# Getting error using sequence and bind variables together in oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am using an insert statement getting called from a NodeJs file. Sample insert statement is as shown below:

```
insert into(id, name, description) values (:ID, :NAME, :DESCRIPTION);
```

The above mentioned statement works properly.

But, if i change this statement to use sequence along with bind variables as shown below, getting

> "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number".

```
insert into(id, name, description) values (s_id.nextval, :NAME, :DESCRIPTION);
```

Can anyone let me know what is wrong in this?

Comment: Did you change the part of your code (not shown) which supplies the bind *values*? I'm guessing that is still trying to pass three values, or is referring to bind positions 2 and 3 (instead of 1 and 2)?

Comment: @Alex Poole: Thanks for the right guess. Yes, that was the issue. The request was sending 3 bind variables along with the ID value. Once, i change the request format to send only 2 bind variables, the code is working fine. Thanks again for the right pathway shown.